# Not able to set up my loopback model.Error:Persisted model has not been correctly attached to a DataSource

Tags: loopback

```
restraunt.json file

`{
  "name": "restraunt",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}`

restraunt.js file

`module.exports = function(Restraunt) {
    Restraunt.find({where:{id:1}}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
};`

model-config.json  file
`"restraunt": {
    "dataSource": "restrauntManagement"
  }`

datasources.json file
`{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "restrauntManagement": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 0,
    "url": "",
    "database": "restraunt-management",
    "password": "restraunt-management",
    "name": "restrauntManagement",
    "user": "rohit",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
}`
```

I am able to get,put,post from the explorer which means the sql db has been set up properly but i am not able to 'find' from restraunt.js file.It throws an error.
"Error: Cannot call restraunt.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource"

Answer (score 2):

Besides that executing code in boot folder, there's a possibility to use event, emitted after attaching the model.
You can write your code right in model.js, not in boot folder.

Looks like:

```
Model.once("attached", function () {})

Model = Accounts (for example).
```

I know, this is an old topic, but maybe this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing mysql connector again:

```
npm i -S loopback-connector-mysql
```

Take a look at your datasources.json, because mysql's port might be wrong, default port is 3306, also you could try changing localhost to 0.0.0.0.

```
"restrauntManagement": {
    "host": "localhost", /* if you're using docker, you need to set it to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost */
    "port": 0, /* default port is 3306 */
    "url": "",
    "database": "restraunt-management",
    "password": "restraunt-management",
    "name": "restrauntManagement", 
    "user": "rohit",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
```

model-config.json must be:

```
"restraunt": {
    "dataSource": "restrauntManagement" /* this name must be the same name in datasources object key (in your case it is restrauntManagement not the connector name which is mysql) */
  }
```

You also need to execute the migration for restaurant model:

create migration.js at /server/boot and add this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(server) {
  var mysql = server.dataSources.mysql; 

  mysql.autoupdate('restraunt');
};
```

you need to migrate every single model you'll use it. you also need to migrate the default models (ACL, AccessToken, etc...) if you're going to attach them to a datasource.

Also in the docs says you can't perform any operation inside the model.js file because the system (at that point) it is not fully loaded. Any operation you need to execute must be inside a .js file in the /boot directory because the system is completely loaded there. You can perform operations inside remote methods because the system is loaded as well.

Comment: added the code to migration.js. I replaced server.dataSources.mysql; with server.dataSources.restrauntManagment; because thats the name of my sql db. But still getting the same error

Comment: also when i used server.dataSources.mysql; and i did console.log(server.dataSources.mysql) its showing 'undefined'

Comment: I believe you mean restaurant instead of restraunt.

Comment: yup thats a spelling mistake i have done. But its restraunt throughout my app. So that should not be a problem i suppose.

Comment: still getting the same error. :/. Tried everything. What i cant understand is that its working fine with the loopback explorer. I am able to do all CRUD operations. Its only in the model.js file where i am getting error : 'Persisted model is not attached to a datasource'. Also when i am printing 'restraunt' in restraunt.js it shows me all the methods including find,create etc.

Comment: Got it!!i was making an error in model.js file....I was calling restraunt.find directly and not inside a remote method. :D

Comment: wow, yeah, there is something like that in the docs. Inside the model.js the system was not entirely loaded, so any initialization must be executed inside /boot directory because the system is already loaded there. when you execute something inside a remote method the same principle applies.